# How do I append to a list in F# rather than prepend?

Tags: f#

Prepending to a list in F# is somewhat annoying because once you're done you have to reverse it. Is there a way to build a list straight from start?

Comment: it might be helpful to know the context of what you're trying to do.

Comment: here, for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18840705/what-am-i-doing-wrong-in-chunking-a-list-in-f

Answer (score 9):

If you need to append elements to the end, you can use the type known as `DList`. There is an [implementation available in FSharpX](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpx/blob/master/src/FSharpx.Core/Collections/DList2.fsi).

However, there is some runtime overhead associated with this (e.g. see the [comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18595597/is-using-a-stringbuilder-a-right-thing-to-do-in-f)) and so I think that building list by prepending and then reversing is generally going to be more efficient. It is also quite standard thing to do in functional programming - it may look a bit confusing at first, but it is a very common "design pattern" when implementing recursive functions that walk over lists, so I would not try to avoid it.

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing wrong with prepending and reversing the list. You can use append (`@`) on a single-element list, but it is a code smell. A tolerable (tail-recursive) approach is:

```
let appendSingle xs x =
    [ yield! xs
      yield x ]
```

All the above solutions have O(n) execution time.
For your use case, you could keep a private [ResizeArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353447.aspx) to avoid the use of reverse. It is fine since mutability is hidden. Compare this function

```
let filter f l = 
  let rec loop acc l =
    match l with 
    | [] -> List.rev acc                        
    | x::xs when f x -> loop (x::acc) xs  
    | x::xs -> loop acc xs
  loop [] l
```

with its more efficient counterpart

```
let filter f l = 
  let rec loop (acc : ResizeArray<_>) l =
    match l with 
    | [] -> Seq.toList acc                        
    | x::xs when f x -> 
        acc.Add(x)  
        loop acc xs  
    | x::xs -> loop acc xs
  loop (ResizeArray()) l
```

Comment: Why do you say using append (@) with a single element list a code smell? It's a perfectly valid approach IMHO. You're `appendSingle` function does basicly the same than xs @ [x] with the same performance characteristics but in a more complicated way

Comment: I should have said both are unidiomatic and the second one is tolerable due to tail-recursiveness.

Answer (score 4):

Append `x` to `xs` like this:

```
xs @ [x]
```

Note that this is O(n).

Comment: Maybe f# has DList like Haskell, so you can get O(1) appends?

Comment: I'm sure there are libraries implementing lists with append and catenable lists but there is basically no demand for this in the real world

Answer (score 3):

Referring back to your [original code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18840705/what-am-i-doing-wrong-in-chunking-a-list-in-f), I think what you are looking for is to use [`List.foldBack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353846.aspx) rather than [`List.fold`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353894.aspx). Essentially, `foldBack` repeatedly applies the `folder` function starting from the end of the list rather than from the start of the list. It's not as efficient as `fold` but it's better to use `foldBack` and avoid reversing the list.

With `foldBack`, your accumulation function `folder` is applied to a list `x0::x1::...::xlast` as follows, where the initial argument to `folder` is`init`:

```
folder x0 (folder x1 ( ... (folder xlast init) ... ) )
```

c.f. `fold`

```
folder (... (folder (folder init x0) x1) ...) xlast
```

There are some other answers to your original question that suggest alternative solutions, but sticking with your code, substituting `foldBack` for `fold` results in a first implementation

```
let chunkOrig items chunkSize =
    let folder =
        fun x (result, chunk) ->
            if List.length chunk < chunkSize then
                (result, x::chunk)
            else
                (chunk::result, [x])
    let (a,b) = List.foldBack folder items ([], []) 
    b::a
```

Already this is a lot simpler, as all the list reversing has gone. And it *seems* to work.

```
> chunkOrig [1..10] 2;;
val it : int list list = [[1; 2]; [3; 4]; [5; 6]; [7; 8]; [9; 10]]
```

However when your list doesn't divide into equal chunks it goes wrong, because `foldBack` starts from the last element.

```
> chunkOrig [1..11] 2;;
val it : int list list = [[1]; [2; 3]; [4; 5]; [6; 7]; [8; 9]; [10; 11]]
```

What you need to do is parameterise your local function `folder` by the length remaining in the current chunk rather than by the chunk itself.

```
let chunk items chunkSize =
    let folder =
        fun x (result, lenLeft) ->
        if lenLeft > 0 then
            match result with
               | [] -> ([[x]], lenLeft-1)
               | r0::rtail -> ((x::r0)::rtail, lenLeft-1)
        else
            ([x]::result, chunkSize-1)
    let (result, lenLeft) = List.foldBack folder items ([], (List.length items) % chunkSize) 
    result

> chunk [1..10] 2;;
val it : int list list = [[1; 2]; [3; 4]; [5; 6]; [7; 8]; [9; 10]]

> chunk [1..11] 2;;
val it : int list list = [[1; 2]; [3; 4]; [5; 6]; [7; 8]; [9; 10]; [11]]
```